# PHP POST Method always Null

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, apache, post, amazon-ec2

https://www.xbyte.in/Console/Image.php is the Link

PHP File Code

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Output **Array()**

You can check the API using this website https://reqbin.com/

I think its because im not giving any auth details and the server's default configuration requires auth. I'm not sure. If so, how do i disable it and allow all PHP Post methods without any Auth

Im using AWS EC2 'Amazon Linux AMI2'

Comment: The reason it is returning `Array ()` is because you are not posting anything to it. I just made a post request to that file and it works as expected.

Comment: You have to actually POST something in order to get something in $_POST. It's got nothing to do with authentication. Also note your PHP version is quite old and well beyond end of life.

Comment: I did post. That's the reason i put this link in here where you can try posting too. @mulquin

Comment: I did post. Please check it out using the link provided. @AlexHowansky

Comment: It works just fine. Use `FORM URL Encoded`, not JSON.

Comment: Can you please give me more details of what you did? @AlexHowansky

Comment: Click the `Content` tab, then select `FORM URL Encoded`. A default PHP POST expects to get content this way, like from submitting a form.

Comment: It's unclear how you concluded this had anything to do with authentication. If auth had failed, you'd get no response at all from the PHP because the request would never reach it, you'd be redirected to a 403 response instead. Instead you got a response from PHP, just not the one you were expecting.

Comment: P.s. why did you set `header('Content-Type: application/json');` when the code just outputs some print_r data, and makes no attempt to return any JSON? The type of content you output is supposed to match the type of content you tell the client (via the content-type header) it's going to contain